# JavaScript - return length of current URL

Tags: javascript

I've been searching and I can't find a JavaScript method or anything that may give me the length of the URL of the page currently shown. It would be helpful for a little project of mine. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using `document.URL.length`?

Comment: window.location.toString().length would do it also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the length of the URL by using `.length`:

```
 location.href.length
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
alert(document.URL.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

The location.href returns the length of the whole URL. If you need to find the URL size with out the http:// just subtract from the x.length.

```
var x = location.href;
alert(x.length);
```